# Android Universal Image Loader, display top section of image

Tags: android, imageview, android-image, universal-image-loader

I've done some searching, but I haven't been able to find a similar enough question to what I'm trying to do. Maybe you guys can help me find a good reference or simply help me reach a solution.

From the title you know that I'm trying to use Universal Image Loader v1.8.5 and the Android version I'm working on is v4.0 min sdk v14.

I have `ImageViews` which have a fixed height. The `ScaleType` is set to `centerCrop`. So what ends up happening is the following:

**Actual**

[image: Actual]

What I want to happen is the following where only the section filled in Blue is displayed:

**Desired**

[image: Desired]

How can I get only the top half of a particular image to display? I hesitate to alter the default code in the library since I don't what this to happen for every image which is loaded using the UIL.

**Edit**
For clarification, I'm passing an URL and the destination ImageView to the ImageLoader.displayImage method. So I don't really know what dimensions I'm gonna get for the image which is downloaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621367/how-to-make-images-larger-in-height-in-lazy-list

Comment: Did you try other scale types of ImageView? `fitStart` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you looking for is already in a small easy to use lib called AQuery 
https://code.google.com/p/android-query/ 
you can download an app that have all the functions for this lib at the market
[AndroidQuery](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androidquery)

you will need to use `Aspect Ratio with Anchor` and set `ratio` & `anchor` to **1** which mean to crop the rest of the bitmap from bottom and show the top of the bitmap.